# Is there a easier way to build HTML in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-controls

I am new in Ruby on Rails. When building the page I have to write the plain HTML code manually.

Is any tool like asp.net's web control that can build the page easily?

Comment: You can use the helpers defined in `ActionView::Helpers`. Does that help? ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to look into haml - http://haml-lang.com/

Some people find it more concise and easier to read/write than html.erb.

Comment: +1.  Even if I've never actually used it.  I should give it a chance.  I'm just a little afraid... it's so... weird :)

Comment: Definitely strange at first, but it's hard to go back to writing normal markup with html.erb.

Comment: Easier on the typing fingers, but I found it more brittle - ie a syntax error somewhere in an obscure edge-case will cause the entire page to crash - instead of just failing to render a div properly. YMMV

Comment: @d11wtq, I use HAML a lot and don't find it weird at all. It's HTML shorthand - you don't need to bother with the closing tags, just maintain the proper indentation and nesting. That is similar to how Python works, and, once you've worked with it for a few minutes it's second nature. Of course, having worked with Python might give me a better starting point, but still its not a hard transition, especially if you've used ERB. In my opinion, the HTML generated by HAML is very nice and lean.

Answer (score 1):

Generated code == bad and ugly code, so it is best to write your own HTML.
However you are encouraged to use Rails HTML helpers like [form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) etc.

[Haml](http://haml-lang.com/) and [Slim](http://slim-lang.com/) can save you many keystrokes when writing HTML and will keep it much cleaner.

Comment: Are you for, or against using such tools?

Comment: I always use haml so definitely yes, and slim looks even shorter and neater. Haven't tried it though.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to look into the [dom gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/dom) that I have developed. Using it, you can do things like:

```
require "dom"
["foo".dom(:span, class: "bold"), "bar"].dom(:div).dom(:body).dom(:html)
# => "<html><body><div><span class=\"bold\">foo</span>bar</div></body></html>"
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12249027)

Comment: I don't see how this answer is very different from the accepted answer. I added an example anyway.

Comment: Now that you've edited it to include other details, my comment stands invalidated.

Comment: You may also want to read over [How to offer personal open-source libraries?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229085)